# Nexus 7 rooting false device not responding

Tags: nexus-7, unbricking

I am tried to root the nexus 7, 
at the time of rooting i wrongly deleted the boot.img so device not switch on.

i have tried lot many ways to switch on the device and recover the operating system no use in that,
do u have any way please help me!!!

i need to know how to restore os or install new os to boot the device please help me!!!
any way to recover that problem!!!

what is an need to write the os on flash at first time.

Comment: Have you tried to boot to HBOOT (first screen, when power Nexus 7 with "volume down" pressed). If it can boot - we can use fastboot to flash normal bootloader and recovery.

Comment: ya tried but no use,device given to service center

Comment: Ok, then, please close the question, because completely correct answer isn't possible to detect now...